# Get the full name by userID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Here is the thing: I have a Table named users with this columns(firstName,LastName,UserID,....)

on my website in the URL there is an UserID now on a specific page I have a textbox the question is

how can I get the Full name by the UserID I mean userID 7 = Jason Dow into that textbox

how can I do that in the stored prucedure?

heres what I did:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetFullNameFromUserID]
(   
    @inUserID_INT int
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE
    (
        FirstName varchar(50),
        LastName varchar(50)
    )

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Results (FirstName,LastName)
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    SELECT FirstName,LastName
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserID = @inUserID_INT


        RETURN
END
```

Comment: what is the problem you faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FirstName + ' '  + LastName
FROM Users
WHERE UserID = @inUserID_INT
```

You can concatenate fields using the + sign.

Apologies for the formatting but for some reason I am having difficulty doing this from my phone

Comment: You did it man! Your answer is well formatted and well explained.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is not a stored procedure, it is a function. If you want to create a stored procedure, use something similar to this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetFullNameFromID(
@userID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName, LastName
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserId = @userId
END
```

You could also concatenate the first name and last name into one column like proposed in another answer :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetFullNameFromID(
@userID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) AS FullName
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserId = @userId
END
```

Let's just hope I didn't mess up the syntax.